# mysql counting in a particular time period

Tags: mysql, report

I am a newbie in mysql, and i encounter a difficult problem for me.

I have a table storing some room booking information

```
room_id
booking_start_time
booking_end_time
```

eg.

```
room_id  | booking_start_time | booking_end_time<br>
1        | 2012-01-01 09:00   | 2012-01-01 11:00
1        | 2012-01-02 09:00   | 2012-01-02 10:00
1        | 2012-01-03 08:00   | 2012-01-03 10:00
2        | 2012-01-01 08:00   | 2012-01-01 10:00
3        | 2012-01-01 08:00   | 2012-01-01 09:00
```

And i have to do a report to extract the utilization of a room in a month, that is the number of hours used in a particular period of time
and the format is like the following

```
room 1| room 2
09:00 -10:00|
10:00 -11:00|
```

My question is that how can count the record, if the booking time is across a number of hours like from 9:00 -11:00, but i have to mark 1 hour in the period 09:00 to 10:00 and another 1 hour in the period 10:00 to 11:00.

I really struggle about it.

Your replies are really appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [MySQL Date Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html). Particularly, [`TIME_DIFF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff).

In your case, do a `TIME_DIFF()` for your *booking_time* columns. Combined with a `GROUP BY` for `room_id`, you could easily `SUM()` these for each room in a month.

I recognize that this answer isn't *comprehensive*. I'm encouraging you to learn these functions.

Comment: thanks for your prompt reply.
i do try the time_diff(), it can get the duration time for that room of each booking, I don't know how to count for each period of time like across 2 time slot. Like a booking from 9-11, and i have to count 1 for 9-10, and count 1 for 10-11
is there any function to do it?

Comment: The total `TIME_DIFF()` should give you the *total* time difference. If you want hours have to extract them. I believe there is an `HOUR()` function.